# Unable to add event handler function using jQuery

Tags: jquery, handler

I had the following JavaScript code and it worked correctly -

```
var changeImageButton = document.getElementById("changeImageButton");
changeImageButton.onclick = buttonWasClicked;
```

'buttonWasClicked' is the name of the JavaScript function that gets called when the "changeImageButton" is clicked.

Now, I want to write the same code using JQuery. So I wrote -

```
 $("#changeImageButton").attr("onclick","buttonWasClicked");
```

But it is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's wrong is that you magically switched to using a string, for no apparent reason.

Comment: The reason is that I know very little of jQuery and JavaScript!!

Comment: If I had time to read the whole book, I wouldn't be here in the first place!! Lol.

Comment: If you don't have the time to learn the language and library, then we don't have the time to answer questions that shouldn't need asking... You will need some dedication and allocation of time in order to succeed; we're not here to serve as a shortcut from you committing to that.

Comment: Excuse me, I didn't force anyone to answer. Those who had the time, answered. If you don't have the time, don't answer. I learn a lot easier through getting my questions answered on the forums than trying to figure out everything by myself.

Comment: Stack Overflow is neither a forum nor a personal training area

Comment: Agreed. But it's a site to ask questions. I had a question, I didn't know the answer, so I asked it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks. I have gone through that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this using a few different methods

```
$("#changeImageButton").click(function(){ do_something(); });

$("#changeImageButton").on("click mouseover", function(){ do_something(); });
//this is useful because you can specify more than one event, if you want to
//(so, this code would also trigger when you move the mouse over - not what
// you want, but just for demonstration purposes)

//In jQuery 1.7+ this is doubly useful, because this will also work with elements
//added _after_ the DOM has initially loaded and this code has run
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery has a [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) method for assigning click events.

```
$("#changeImageButton").click(buttonWasClicked);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to register an event, not add an attribute:

```
$("#changeImageButton").click(buttonWasClicked);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#changeImageButton').click(buttonWasClicked);
```

jQuery documentation for click: http://api.jquery.com/click/

Answer (score 0):

What version of jQuery are you using?

Here's the jQuery tutorial on adding event listeners: http://api.jquery.com/click/

```
$("#changeImageButton").click(function() {
  buttonWasClicked();
});
```